# m2eclipse compilation failure

Tags: maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

When I'm running "mvn site" from command line (using far manageR) everything works just excellent, it downloads all the necessary jars to repository and executes tasks.

But when I'm trying to do the same (mvn site) from eclipse using m2eclipse plugin it show me:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jdbc_maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jdbc_maven ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ jdbc_maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[8,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[13,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class JdbcRoleDao
G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[5,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[28,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class User
G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[13,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[19,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class JdbcUserDao
G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[13,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class JdbcRoleDao
G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[28,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class User
G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[19,29] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 9 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.387s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 16 11:05:13 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project jdbc_maven: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[8,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[13,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class JdbcRoleDao
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[5,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[28,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class User
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[13,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[19,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class JdbcUserDao
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcRoleDao.java:[13,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class JdbcRoleDao
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\User.java:[28,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class User
[ERROR] G:\workspace\jdbc_maven\src\main\java\com\nixsolutions\JdbcUserDao.java:[19,29] error: cannot find symbol
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jdbc_maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc_maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jdbc_maven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.169</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin> 
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId> 
                            <version>2.8</version> 
                        </plugin> 
                        <plugin> 
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId> 
                            <version>2.6</version> 
                            <configuration> 
                                <configLocation>sun_checks.xml</configLocation> 
                            </configuration> 
                        </plugin> 
                        <plugin> 
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
                            <version>2.6.1</version> 
                        </plugin> 
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!-- JDK 1.7 COMPILER - DON'T TOUCH -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings> 
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- JDK 1.7 COMPILER - DON'T TOUCH -->

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happen with m2eclipse , its because as you add new dependencies to the pom.xml , m2e will automatically add it to classpath and this classpath generation has some issue.

well a quick and dirty  way to fix would be to

- `Remove the project from the eclipse`
- Now `navigate to the project folder` and `delete .settings directory and .classpath file`
- `Import the project into the eclipse` as a 'Maven Project'

Comment: Remove also `.project` file

Answer (score 1):

Do project->clean (also try to refresh the project) in eclipse. When you compile your code from command line it sometimes causes some issue in eclipse and the code has to be recompiled in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who's using m2eclipse plugin and strugling some proglems, here are my tips:

1) user your own maven, not build in m2eclipse, you can switch to it in m2eclipse preferences

2) change repository location from the foolish one C:\Users\current_user-m2\repository 
to D:\repository or to any other normal path without ~ or any other special liters

3) check everything in console with your own maven before panic. For example my commands like 
mvn site
mvn install 
mvn tomcat:redeploy

work EXCELLENT from console, but fail from inside eclipse. That means m2eclipse parameters are wrong and you should set your own parameters.

4) don't rely on context commands (right click - run as - maven test / site / build) 
create your own command in run as - maven build - in menu choose the correct version of JRE (1.7 in my case) and add any additional parameters don't forget to give this command your name like: "maven tomcat:redeploy JDK 7" - that will give you a good chance to run whatever you want and don't face 90% of m2eclipse problems and bugs.

P.S. I was struggling maven 2 and m2eclipse for more than 20 hours. Hope my tips will be userful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think I have found the solution. The problem is that under run configurations, the maven configuration for your project doesn't have refreshed the new settings made in the overall configuration.

Here is my solution:

1. in the run button (the one with a green triangle), select run configurations
2. move into the categories to the "maven build" category and look for the one of your project
3. checkout that the maven runtime, JRE, and things like that are configured properly: these values aren't refreshed when changed in eclipse
4. apply changes and run

This solution have worked for me (I have been playing with the value maven runtime, changing between embedded and external and that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

same problem when generate docs using m2eclipse, goal javadoc:javadoc or javadoc:jar, meanwhile Project -> Generate Javadoc works fine. It's seem problem in wrong classpath in first case.
 
Workaround:

1.run Project -> Generate Javadoc with check option "Save the settings ofthe Javadoc export as an antscript"
2. javadoc.xml will be generated
3. run m2eclipse, after failure javadoc.sh, options, packages will be in /site/apidocs/
4. take content of classpath from javadoc.xml and put in classpath in options file
5. run ./javadoc.sh

Answer (score 0):

in pom.xml make sure you have the log4j scope at compile

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

It still puts the log4j.jars into the .war.